# How to sort ordering of store view change list in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, store-view, sort, store-switcher

[image]

I want to sort alphabetically this store view change list. Can anyone help with how can I do this in magneto 2.3.4?

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution .override Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher

here change function

```
public function getWebsites()
{
    $websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    if ($websiteIds = $this->getWebsiteIds()) {
        $websites = array_intersect_key($websites, array_flip($websiteIds));
    }
    
    
    # get a list of sort columns and their data to pass to array_multisort
    $sort = array();
    foreach($websites as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['name'][$k] = strtoupper($v['name']);
    }
    # sort by event_type desc and then title asc
    array_multisort($sort['name'], SORT_ASC,$websites);

    return $websites;
}
```